# How to develop WebRTC application for beginners?

Tags: c++, web-applications, webrtc

I am new in WebRTC. I have good knowledge of ICE/STUN/TURN. I want to develop a WebRTC application using my implementations of ICE/STUN/TURN which is been implemented in C++. Is the C++ library can be used for a web application of WebRTC? If yes, how?

Can you give me some open source ICE library names which can be used in WebRTC also?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: updated April 2016

For those getting started on ICE, STUN and TURN (and WebRTC in general) I recommend the resources linked to from [webrtc.org/start](https://web.archive.org/web/20191225145501/https://webrtc.org/start/).

Resources for developers working on iOS or Android apps using the native WebRTC APIs are available at [webrtc.org/native-code](https://web.archive.org/web/20191115053529/https://webrtc.org/native-code/).

Shameless self promotion, but for further information about ICE I suggest you look at the [WebRTC Infrastructure](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) article I wrote for HTML5 Rocks.

Comment: Sam, Thanks for your kind cooperation. I have already seen these links. But I am bit confused about ICE/STUN/TURN implementation in WebRTC. I want use my implementation. To enable that what to do?

Comment: Thanks @SemicolonWarrier – updated with new links and resources.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential resource to consider is the open source Mobicents SIP Servlets project, which provides examples how to write server code for managing WebRTC calls.

Here is a video demo:
http://vimeo.com/51744602

Here is a blog how to run WebRTC apps on CloudBees one of the popular Java PaaS:
http://www.telestax.com/webrtc_cloudbees/

If you are not a Java developer, you can take a look at Restcomm and keep an eye on upcoming announcements for WebRTC support:
https://code.google.com/p/restcomm/